# JBPM : couldn't deploy process archives : null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jbpm

Can any body help in deploying JBPM process definition using ant.

In that deployment process I am facing this error :

[deployToServer] deploying par ...

BUILD FAILED
F:\JBPM_NEW_GRAILS_WORKSPACE\jbpm5webexample\build.xml:43: couldn't deploy process archives : null

My Build.xml file is
For process Deployment in build.xml entry are :

```
<target name="deployProcess" description="deploys the process definition">
   <echo>Deploy the process definition</echo>
   <taskdef name="deployToServer" classname="org.jbpm.ant.DeployProcessToServerTask">
        <classpath refid="exec-classpath"/>
   </taskdef>
   <deployToServer username="root" password="root" serverDeployer="/jbpm5webexample/TaskProcessServlet?action=CreateProcess">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources" includes="*"/>
   </deployToServer>
   <deployToServer>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/resources" includes="*"/>
   </deployToServer>
</target>

<path id="exec-classpath">
        <pathelement path="target/classes" />
        <fileset dir="F:/jbpm-jpdl-3.2.3/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="F:/jbpm-jpdl-3.2.3/" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="C:/java/apache-ant-1.8.1/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="F:/JBPM_NEW_GRAILS_WORKSPACE/jbpm5webexample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="F:/JBPM_NEW_GRAILS_WORKSPACE/jbpm5webexample/target/jbpm5webexample/WEB-INF/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
   </path>
```

Please help me in solving this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to deploy a jBPM v5 example using a jBPM v3 script?

Comment: Thanks Kris,
Actually I am using jBPM 5.2 and trying to deploy process definition.
How could I do 
can you please give me suggestion regarding same.

Comment: Now I download jbpm 5.2 
from :  [http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%205/jbpm-5.2.0.Final/jbpm-5.2.0.Final-installer-full.zip/download]

And Set path as follow : 
`<fileset dir="F:/jbpm-installer/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
  <fileset dir="F:/jbpm-installer/lib/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
  <fileset dir="F:/jbpm-installer/" includes="**/*.jar" />`